# RXSwift ObservableCollection with CombineLatest

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift, combinelatest

I am trying to implement something like this,

```
    let api1 = Observable.of(["documents"])    //Replace with observable to download docs
    let api2 = Observable.of(["applications"]) //Replace with observable to download apps
    let api3 = Observable.of(["videos"])       //Replace with observable to download videos

    Observable.combineLatest(api1, api2, api3){(docs, apps, videos) in
        return (docs, apps, videos)
    }.skipWhile{ (docs, apps, videos) in
        return docs.count == 0 && apps.count == 0 && videos.count == 0
    }.subscribe(onNext:{(docs, apps, videos) in

    })
    .disposed(by:disposeBag)
```

In my case, I am trying to create observables dynamically and add it to an array like this,

```
private var discoverObservables = [Observable<Any>]()


func loadDiscoverFeeds(){
      
        self.feeds.forEach({
            feed in
            switch feed.feedType{
            case "a":
                let observable = self.aObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "")
                self.discoverObservables.append(observable)
                break
            case "b":
                let observable = self.bObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "")
                self.discoverObservables.append(observable)
                break
            case "c":
                let observable = self.cObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "")
                self.discoverObservables.append(observable)
                break
            case "d" :
                let observable = self.dObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "")
                self.discoverObservables.append(observable)
                break
            default:
                break
            
            }
        })
}

    private func aObservable(url : String) -> Observable<A?>{
            return APIManager.shared.getA(url: url)
        }

    private func bObservable(url : String) -> Observable<B?>{
            return APIManager.shared.getB(url: url)
        }


    private func cObservable(url : String) -> Observable<C?>{
            return APIManager.shared.getC(url: url)
        }
```

But this is not working because discoverObservables array is expecting the value of Type `Observable<Any>` and I am trying to add **Observable<A?>**

How can I do this correctly, I want to make sure all the observables return data before I start processing the data.

**Edit**
I am trying to load data from different sources before that is added to the view, basically, I have a collectionview, each section loads data from different API, I am trying to get all the required data from all sources before that is added to collection view.

Comment: You show the declaration for `aObservable(url:)` but what are the declarations for `bObservable(url:)` and `cObserrvable(url:)`? What do they return?

Comment: Also, Observables should never be `var`s. You are doing something fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: @DanielT. I have added some details hope it helps.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add the same protocol to A, B and C.

```
protocol YourProtocol {...}

class A: YourProtocol {...}
class B: YourProtocol {...}
class C: YourProtocol {...}
```

Then you can make :

```
private var discoverObservables = [Observable<YourProtocol>]()
```

Answer (score 1):

The first code block seems to be doing the job with one exception, the condition checks if all of the (docs, apps, videos) are empty, perhaps you wanted to use `||` instead of `&&`.

As for the second code block with an array, I did something that could help.

```
    struct A {}
    
    let observable1 = Observable.just(A())
    let observable2 = Observable.just(A())
    let observable3 = Observable.just(A())

    let observables: [Observable<A>] = [observable1, observable2, observable3]
    
    Observable.combineLatest(observables).skipWhile { (streams) -> Bool in
        streams.forEach {
            if $0.count == 0 { return true }
        }
        return false
    }.subscribe(...
```

This subscription will result with `Observable<[A]>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to specifically address this from your question: "I want to make sure all the observables return data before I start processing the data."

Strictly speaking, you probably don't want an `Any` structure. Better would be a protocol or enum. I see that other answers have addressed the protocol idea so I will use the enum idea:

```
enum EndpointResponse {
    case a(A?)
    case b(B?)
    // etc...
}

let responses = Observable.zip(
    feeds.map { (feed) -> Observable<EndpointResponse> in
        switch feed.feedType {
        case "a":
            return aObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "").map { EndpointResponse.a($0) }
        case "b":
            return bObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "").map { EndpointResponse.b($0) }
        default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
)
```

The above `responses` observable will contain an array of all the responses once they have all emitted values. In other words, the `zip` operator will gather up all the responses from all the network calls and emit a single array containing all of them.

**My Previous answer:**

There really isn't a lot of information to go on in the question, but something like this answers the direct question you ask about converting an `Observable<X>` to an `Observable<Any>`...

```
let discoverObservables = Observable.zip(
    feeds.map { (feed) -> Observable<Any> in
        switch feed.feedType {
        case "a":
            return aObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "").map { $0 as Any }
        case "b":
            return bObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "").map { $0 as Any }
        case "c":
            return cObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "").map { $0 as Any }
        case "d":
            return dObservable(url: feed.feedURL ?? "").map { $0 as Any }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
)
```